# How to auto update a Mercurial push

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

The below hook isn't auto updating the repository I'm pushing to.  I've verified that I have proper permissions as I'm updating via ssh with the owner of the files.

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

When I try this without `>&2` I get no result either.

Answer (score 1):

In which .hgrc file is that hook found?   Try changing it to:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = echo I RAN
```

to see if it's being run at all